# How to consume highland stream with an async function?

Tags: asynchronous, callback, highland.js

What is the correct pattern to consume a highland stream using an async function? It seems the .each method does not work with an node-style async function wrapped using wrapCallback.

I would like to do something like the following. Note that I would like to catch errors generated in the .each function as well and trigger a .done function when all async consumption is done.

```
function asyncConsume(item,cb) {
  // perform async operation based on data stream here
  return cb(null,item);
}
var wrappedFunction = _.wrapCallback(asyncConsume);

highlandStream.each(wrappedFunction).done('All successfully done!')
  .stopOnError(function(err) {
    console.log('This error handler catches errors in .each() as well.');
    });
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can only use an async function with Highland `map` function (after the function has been `wrapCallback`ed). The map does not actually call the function, so you need a Highland `series` or `parallel` call to follow and actually handle the calls.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `flatMap` here because you are transforming your items into a new stream:

```
highlandStream
  .flatMap(function(item) {
    return wrappedFunction(item);
}).each(someFn).done('All successfully done!')
  .stopOnError(function(err) {
    console.log('This error handler catches errors in .each() as well.');
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't really need to transform the value using flatMap (I want to trigger an email to send for each item in the stream in my case), but I have tried flatMap and it does seem to be the best solution for now. That way I can put the error handler after it to catch errors after the async operation as well.

Comment: What I meant is that you are transforming your input to flatMap into an async operation.